# How to add bootnodes option in running validator node?

Tags: validator, bootnode

I have to set up a network using the substrate. I am able to run the first node as boot node. now I have to run 3 more nodes as validator. Should I need to provide the first node IP as boot node URL or need to provide all four nodes (3 validator nodes + 1 boot node) as bootnode url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bootstrap a small test network of 4 nodes, you only need that one boot node, and the rest can use it.

For larger networks, it makes sense to have multiple redundant boot nodes.

Comment: What happens if the only boot node goes offline? Is block production moving on and when the boot node reconnects it catches up with the rest of them?

Comment: Yes. The bootnode is only used to connect new computers to the overall network. Once your other machines have paired, you could remove the bootnode and nothing would change for the computers on the existing network.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Hi following up on your comment. Would the validators automatically pair themselves once they join the network (hence not requiring the bootnodes anymore), or do we explicitly need to specify them to pair up?

Comment: Your node will automatically connect to more peers. The node logs will tell you how many peers you have, for example `2022-11-15 02:50:57  Idle (16 peers), best: #15335210 (0x03ba…9d3a), finalized #15335205 (0x84f8…9c6c), ⬇ 73.3kiB/s ⬆ 36.1kiB/s    
`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide bootnode url of all validator nodes as it is not necessary.If for some reason you are not confident about the node you want to connect is receiving connections you can give url of other bootnodes.

As Shawn Tabrizi already answered it makes more sense for larger networks.